# Classic ASP with Expression Web 2 and Vista

Tags: asp-classic, windows-vista, expression-web

I have previously used Expression Web with XP and MS Server 2003 and in each case I am able to preview .asp pages in the browser.

I have now transferred to Vista and get the error "this page may contain dynamic content that requires a Web server...."
On the other hand should I wish to preview an HTML page there is no problem.

I am aware that Expression does not support Classic ASP IntelliSense, but I can live with that.....if I have to.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the (HTML) pages you are able to preview are not being served by a web server.

Are you able to confirm that they are being presented on the http (http://...) protocol and not the local file protocol (file:///...)?

Comment: You are right.
When I was operating with XP I set up a new website with the address http://ComputerName/WebsiteName.
Now I am unable to do so  - an error message comes up suggesting that either FPSE are not installed (they are) .

Comment: What happens if you do 'File > Open Site...', do you get a list of sites under your web root?
Do you actually have IIS installed (check in Programs and Features, Windows Components)?